# Refactoring socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, refactoring

I am trying to create an application that is an online multiplayer version of the board game Pentago. I also want to have chat features in this application.

My query is this: In my application, the client-side code currently looks very messy and is getting difficult to debug as all functionality (game-related and chat related) sits in one file. This file is now hundreds of lines long. I want to refactor the code so that variables/functions for game setup, gameplay, starting a new game, chatting can all reside in their own files. The issue I am facing is I do not know how to create these files such that all of them behave as one socket and not a completely new socket per file.

Is there a way to export const `socket = io() object`? Or somehow bind all public files to respond/emit under the same socket.id? Similarly, is there any way to break up the emits/ons in server-side js file into more specific functional files?

Comment: How is your client code currently structured?  Are you using the newer `import/export` features?  Or just separate script files?  Or bundling and transpiling?

Comment: Currently, I am calling `const socket = io()` right at the beginning of one file, and all my client-side code resides in this one file.

Comment: Well, perhaps this answer from earlier today would help you: [Pass socket.io to router module in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578047/pass-socket-io-to-router-module-in-node-js/61578306#61578306).